# Perl's Unicode::UCD::charscript function isn't identifying my character

Tags: perl, unicode

The character here is 户, which is U+6237 CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-6237.  But the `charscript` function provided by the standard `Unicode::UCD` module is returning an undefined value:

```
    perl -MUnicode::UCD=charscript -wle 'print charscript(chr(0x6237)) // "undef"'
```

This prints `undef`.  I am using Perl 5.14.2 or 5.18.1; the problem occurs with both versions.

I understand that the character could just as easily be part of a Japanese or even a Korean text, but `charscript` doesn't even say something like "CJK ideograph"; instead it just returns undef, which is not useful.

What I really want to do is to write a program that I can use to filter my incoming email; messages with subjects in Chinese should be flagged. (I can't read Chinese, and legitimate correspondents know this, and so don't send me mail written in Chinese.)  And I have a perfectly good subject line written in Chinese, so I thought to use `charscript` to help recognize that, but it seems that it doesn't.

- Why doesn't `charscript` return something more useful than undef here?
- Is `charscript` the right thing to use for this?
- If not, what is?

[ Added a little later: I checked the relevant Unicode data file, [`Scripts.txt`](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/Scripts.txt), and it identifies the script of this character as `Han`, which, had it been returned by `charscript`, I would have considered an acceptable result. So the problem really seems to be with the software, and not with my understanding of Unicode. ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the examples. The usage is

```
charscript(0x6237)
```

or

```
charscript('Han')
```

You're doing

```
charscript('户')
```